# How to accumulate count in nested for loops?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, nested-loops

I have the following:

```
(let ((count 0))
  (loop for i from 1 to 3 do
        (loop for j from 1 to 3 do
              (loop for k from 1 to 3 do
                    (setq count (+ 1 count))))
        finally (return count)))
```

Which is the fastest, lispish, construct to do this?

Comment: Please format & edit your question and indent your code (by starting code lines with 4 spaces). Otherwise, your way is probably good enough.

Answer (score 7):

What is the best way to do it depends on the purpose of the code, i.e. why you are nesting the three loops.

In your specific case, the fastest and shortest answer is `(* 3 3 3)` or `27`

More generally, a possible improvement is to replace `(setq count (+ 1 count))` with `(incf count)`

You can also write the loops as

```
(loop for i from 1 to 3 summing
   (loop for j from 1 to 3 summing
      (loop for k from 1 to 3 summing 1)))
```

Except for the non-looping answers, the speed should be about the same for all versions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `count` loop keyword in the innermost loop and `sum` the results in the outer loops:

```
(loop :for i :below 3
      :sum (loop :for j :below 3
                 :sum (loop :for k :below 3
                            :count t)))
```